# Get the id of elements with same class

Tags: jquery, html

How to get each attr id for elements that have the same class?

```
var id = $('.class').attr('id');
```

But when I do a console.log it only returns one id even though I have more than one id and multiple divs with same classes.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use [**map()**](http://api.jquery.com/map/)

```js
var ids = $('.class').map(function() {
  return $(this).attr('id');
});
console.log(ids);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="class" id="1"></div>
<div class="class" id="2"></div>
<div class="class" id="3"></div>
```

Comment: to get the array list `ids = ids.toArray()`

Answer (score 5):

use jquery each function.

```
var i = 0;
var ids = [];  
    $(".class").each(function(){
        ids[i++] =  $(this).attr("id"); //this.id
        });
```

Comment: I think he has more than ".class" to check. Unknown Classnames with multiple occurrences.

Comment: For that there should be some extra information. but just to get id of each element having same class. I think this would be good

Comment: Farhan modified it ... first code was good for me. It was like this: $(".class").each(function(){
         $(this).attr("id"); //this.id
        }); Thanks.

Comment: @user3275665 doesn't appear to have any valid answer in edit history but maybe missing it. Anyway, using `map()` is better

Answer (score 3):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>jQuery.map demo</title>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="map-test" id="1"></div>
        <div class="map-test" id="21"></div>
        <div class="map-test" id="31"></div>
        <div class="map-test" id="41"></div>
        <div class="map-test" id="51"></div>
        <div class="map-test" id="61"></div>
        <div class="map-test" id="71"></div>
        <div class="map-test"></div>
        <script>
            var arr = jQuery.map(jQuery('.map-test'),function(n,i){
                return jQuery(n).attr('id');
            });
            console.log(arr);
            //will print ["1", "21", "31", "41", "51", "61", "71"]
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
var ids = $('.class').map(function() {
    return this.id;
}).get();
console.log(1, ids);

//For modern browsers with arrow functions
ids = $('.class').map((i, item)=>item.id).get();
console.log(2, ids);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="class" id="a"></div>
<div class="class" id="b"></div>
<div class="class" id="c"></div>
```

Comment: nice to know about .get()